# Measuring packet loss through Android N

Tags: android, networking, tcp, udp, packet-loss

I am working on a project that is meant for testing network diagnostics. The section I'm working on now involves testing TCP and UDP connections. One of the points of measurement is packet loss for both TCP and UDP.

In the past I used: `'/statistics/rx_dropped'` (*I'm leaving off the beginning portion of that file path*), suffice to say it points to the number of packets dropped in total on a specified network interface.

However, in **Android N** this file requires **root** to read and I can't assume that the phone this app will be on is rooted.

**Does anyone have a decent way of measuring packet loss on the client side for at least TCP that doesn't require rooting?**

I am mostly aware of networking jargon so don't be shy, the reason I ask is because the way I measure has to be fairly elegant (either using some existing java/android library or finding a legal way of reading packet loss from the device).